# Image publish best practices for restricted images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my use case, I have to publish images to a website. However, the images might be restricted for some period of time. What are the best practices to show broken images during that time?

My approach so far:

- Use onerror and onload handlers of `<img>` tag as mentioned [here](http://www.daveoncode.com/2010/08/20/image-background-fallback-img-tag-error-handlers/)
- Use [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) to placehold all broken images

I will be very thankful for any guidelines/opinions/best-practices on this.
Also, how do I gracefully fallback for legacy systems where I don't have the option to handle events on `<img>` element.
Images already have `ALT` attribute so guidelines on those lines can be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this with `jQuery` so I assume that's an option.

The simplest solution is indeed to detect an error and replace the image in that case:

```
$('img.myChangingImageClass').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'notavailableYet.png');
});
```

It's simple, straightforward, and works on all modern browsers.

Matt suggested using event delegation, which is useful if you might be adding images at a later point. Also, it attaches one event for the entire page, instead of an event per image. this can be done the following way:

```
$(document).on('error', 'img.myChangingImageClass', function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'notavailableYet.png'); 
});
```

Since you already have an 'alt' attribute that's ok for systems that can't display images and for SEO. If you'd like you can use `placehold.it` for the replacement image, but I don't think that's needed (that depends on your use case). You can even `.hide()` the image or play with that.

Comment: FWIW, it might be better using event delegation here, rather than attaching to the element directly. The main benefit is that you can bind the handler immediately (e.g. to the `document`), which means you won't have any chance of the `error` event being fired before you've had chance to attach the handler. Secondly, you only attach one handler per-page, rather than one per-element. `$(document).on('error', 'img.myChangingImageClass', function () {  /* Handler you already have */; });`

Comment: Hi Benzamin. I am also thinking on the same lines, however, even though short and crisp, I am not able to validate if its the best practice. For eg, consider a client using the webapp launches a campaign and all images on that page will be available, say, 2 days from today? So, most images will be 'notAvailableYet'. Not too sure but I will be very thankful if you can point me to some guidelines/design patterns on this?

Comment: @gashu Every image that is _not_ yet available will not be loaded. The minute it becomes available it will be loaded. This is a fairly simple task and my answer is the _de facto_ standard way to handle it. I'm sure I can find a fancy design pattern name for it (like chain of responsibility or something along those lines), that wouldn't do your production code much good though :)

Comment: Thanks @Matt for suggesting event delegation here. I guess thats indeed the best option for such situations. Marking Benzamin's edited answer as correct.